# mysql difference between date in () and dateadd

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a reasonably simple query, which operates on a large dataset.

When I use the IN operator, I get a certain result which I believe is correct.
When I use DATE_ADD(), I get a result which I believe is incorrect.

The query is the following:(the 2 commented lines are the 2 options)

```
SELECT 
    e.date, er.ratio, e.total as recalc
FROM
    equity e
        JOIN
    exchange_rate er ON e.date = er.date
        AND LOWER(er.currency) = LOWER(e.currency)
    join account a
        on e.account = a.id
WHERE
    -- e.date >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 5 DAY)
    -- e.date in ('2016-11-14','2016-11-15','2016-11-16')
    and a.lynx_country = 'BE'
```

the values in brackets after IN are the values returned when I would do a

```
SELECT 
    distinct date
FROM
    equity e
WHERE
    e.date >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 5 DAY)
```

Furthermore, the resultset is the same for the 2 queries, but when I add a wrapper query, I get a significant difference

full query including wrapper:

```
    select ROUND(SUM(total) / ratio, 2) as agg, date
from (
SELECT 
    e.date, er.ratio, e.total
FROM
    equity e
        JOIN
    exchange_rate er ON e.date = er.date
        AND LOWER(er.currency) = LOWER(e.currency)
    join account a
        on e.account = a.id
WHERE
    e.date >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 5 DAY)
    -- e.date in ('2016-11-14','2016-11-15','2016-11-16')
    and a.lynx_country = 'BE'
    ) dummy
    group by date
```

Wrong Result: DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 5 DAY)

```
agg         | date
------------------------
68833599.13 | 2016-11-14
69350727.47 | 2016-11-15
69351461.28 | 2016-11-16
```

Correct Result: in ('2016-11-14','2016-11-15','2016-11-16')

```
agg          | date
-------------------------
101956327.03 |  2016-11-14
102722297.52 |  2016-11-15
102723384.45 |  2016-11-16
```

All help appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing what is really being varied between the two queries.  The `WHERE` clause is changing, but also in the second query you are doing an aggregation.

Comment: Is the output of the first query (without the aggregating wrapper) the same for both variants? And what is the output?

Comment: Yes, and the output is 9000 rows

Comment: Can you specify the data type of column "equity.date" please? and version of MySQL?

Comment: type is "date", version is 5.6.23